# How to get input on textchanged on winform

Tags: winforms

I want to wait to user input on winform. Without using textbox or other control. just the form it self handle the input.
I've try to add KeyPress and TextChanged Events to the form, both with no successes. What am I doing wrong?

thanks :)

Comment: Show some code.  Are there any controls that have the focus on the form?

Comment: There is no code to show. I use generic code from the designer.

Comment: What do you mean "generic code from the designer" The only code that will be there is code you write. It will make the procedures for you but you have to decide what goes on in those procedures.

Comment: I am  afraid you missing the point... there is generic code from the designer when you add an event to a control. You will get the method to implemnts the events such as private void Screen1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {}. of course I need to implements those method, but my question its not about that. I just want to know why these method don't work when I implement them on the form and not on a general control.

Comment: A WinForm is a container, not a control. You could add a textbox (multiline=true) and dock it to fill the container. If you just want to capture keystrokes try setting the KeyPreview property on the WinForm.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you're asking why double clicking on a control to create an event handler works, but typing the exact same method signature doesn't.  The reason for this is the designer generates code that winds up in the `.Designer.cs` file.  If you look in there, you'll find (eventually -- there's a lot of code generated for forms...) a line linking the actual event the button raises to the handler method it generates; something like this:

```
button1.Click += button1_Clicked;
```

This is the magic that doesn't happen when you manually type the signature for `button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)` directly in the Form1.cs file.

But I might have misread your comments/question entirely, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want handle keyboard input on the `Form`:

- Create a event handler for `Form.KeyPress` - event
- Set property `KeyPreview` = true (Through designer for example)
- Then before pressing keys be sure that `Form` have focused

[Keyboard input on the Form level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

About `TextChanged` event:

From MSDN:

> This event is raised if the Text property is changed by either a
>   programmatic modification or user interaction.

So `TextChanged` event must be raised at least on the initialization of form, when `.Text` property be changed. And of course, everytime you change this property as:  `_myForm.Text = "my new form"`
In your case `TextChanged` event not raised because(I assume) Event handler was added after `InitializeComponent()` method was called. Where (C#)`this.Text = "MyForm"` was called

[TextChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)